Why does ethanol, despite having a lower boiling point than benzene, has a higher heat of vaporization?
At 1 atm of pressure, ethanol boils at 78.37°C with a heat of vaporization equal to 39.3 KJ/mol, and Benzene boils at 80.1°C with a heat of vaporization equal to 31.0 KJ/mol.
Here are my assumptions:
Ethanol vapor pressure at 78.37°C = Benzene vapor pressure at 80.1°C
Ethanol vapor pressure at 78.37°C > Benzene vapor pressure at 78.37°C
Boiling point ∝ intermolecular forces
Vapor pressure ∝ 1/intermolecular forces
Ethanol has higher vapor pressure and lower boiling point than benzene,
so it has weaker intermolecular forces.
The higher the intermolecular forces, the higher the energy required to overcome them in the transform from the liquid to the gaseous state
heat of vaporization ∝ intermolecular forces
so it seems to me that: boiling point ∝ intermolecular forces ∝ heat of vaporization
and I'd imagine Benzene which has a higher boiling point than ethanol, to also have a higher heat of vaporization, but that doesn't seem to be the case.
Is there something incorrect about my assumption, or maybe some factors that I haven't considered that may change the outcome?

I think you have made correct assumptions. What seems like an inconsistency is because the boiling point is related to the entropy of vaporization as well as the enthalpy. Because of a high degree of hydrogen bonding in liquid ethanol (intermolecular forces again), it has a higher degree of order (or lower number of available microstates) than benzene, and the entropy of vaporization is therefore higher for ethanol than for benzene.
For nonpolar liquids such as benzene, the ratio between the enthalpy of vaporization and the boiling temperature is approximately equal to the entropy of vaporization, and this ratio has been observed to be fairly constant. This is known as Trouton's rule and is sometimes used to calculate the enthalpy of vaporization for a compound if you only know its boiling point, using another compound's enthalpy of vaporization.
For polar compounds, this doesn't really work, however. Water, for instance, has a much larger enthalpy of vaporization than would be expected if you would use Trouton's rule to calculate it.

Lower configuration entropy in liquid ethanol explains why it has higher vaporization heat, but how to explain it has also higher vapor pressure? Due to hydrogen bonds in liquid ethanol, one would expect bonding energy between molecules to be greater and vapor pressure to be lower, like it is for water vs H$_2$S.

@JánLalinský I am not sure I understand what you mean. Ethanol has a lower vapor pressure than benzene...
